# How to hide an input-box with CSS

Tags: javascript, css, forms

The code underneath will show Fax and an input-box. I manage to hide the text "Fax" but I'm not able to hide the input-box. How can I hide the input-box using CSS and Javascript?

```
<div class="field">
    <label for="billing:fax">Fax</label>
    <div class="input-box">
       <input id="billing:fax" class="input-text " type="text" title="Faxnummer"    value="" name="billing[fax]">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can try .input-box > input {display:none;}

Comment: _"I manage to hide the text Fax"_ So how'd you do that? And where's the CSS you tried?

Comment: Here's the CSS code that hide the text Fax: 
    label[for="billing:fax"] { display:none; }

Comment: And did you try using `display:none` with your input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide that specific input you can select it by the ID, but you need to escape the `:`

```css
#billing\:fax {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="field">
  <label for="billing:fax">Fax</label>
  <div class="input-box">
    <input id="billing:fax" class="input-text " type="text" title="Faxnummer" value="" name="billing[fax]">
  </div>
</div>
```

There are of course, many ways to select an element in CSS. Another way would be to use the adjacent sibling (`+`) and descendant (`>`) selectors to get to the input:

```
 label[for="billing:fax"] + div.input-box > input
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript to toggle the input property type="hidden" for the input box.

http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms07.htm

Answer (score 0):

`display: none;` is your best solution if you just wanna hide the field.